# Transforming variable density on log scale with R

Tags: r, scale, logarithm

I want to plot the density of variable whose range is the following:

```
 Min.   :-1214813.0  
 1st Qu.:       1.0  
 Median :      40.0  
 Mean   :     303.2  
 3rd Qu.:     166.0  
 Max.   : 1623990.0
```

The linear plot of the density results in a tall column in range [0,1000], with two very long tails towards positive infinity and negative infinity.
Hence, I'd like to transform the variable to a log scale, so that I can see what's going on around the mean.
For example, I'm thinking of something like:

```
log_values = c( -log10(-values[values<0]), log10(values[values>0]))
```

which results in:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-6.085   0.699   1.708   1.286   2.272   6.211
```

The main problem with this is the fact that it doesn't include the `0` values.
Of course, I can shift all the values away from `0`with `values[values>=0]+1`, but this would introduce some distortion in the data.

What would be an accepted and scientifically solid way of transforming this variable to the log scale?

Comment: How about creating two plots? One for the entire range, the second with just the centre section.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I was wondering if there's a clever transformation :-)

Comment: You could use `sign(values)*log10(abs(values))` to achieve what you constructed above, but then all zero values will become `-Inf`.

Comment: @James they will become `0*(-Inf)` which is `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from transforming, you can manipulate the histogram itself to get an idea about your data. This gives you the advantage that the plots itself stays readible and you get an immediate idea about the distribution in the center. Say we simulate the following data:

```
Data <- c(rnorm(1000,5,10),sample(-10000:10000,10))
> summary(Data)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-9669.000    -2.119     5.332    85.430    12.460  9870.000
```

Then you have a few different approaches. The easiest to see what is going on in the center of your data, is just plot the center of your data. In this case, say I'm interested in what happens between the first and the third quartile, I can plot :

```
hist(Data,
     xlim=c(-30,30),
     breaks=c(min(Data),seq(-30,30,by=5),max(Data))
     main="Center of Data"
     )
```

[image]

If you want to count the tails as well, you can transform your data to collapse the tails and alter the axis to reflect this, as follows :

1. you assign all values outside the range of interest a value that's just outside that range
2. you plot the histogram, binning all extreme values in one bin
3. you construct the X axis with the correct labels
4. you use `axis.break()` from the package `plotrix` to add some breaks on your X axis, indicating the discontinuous axis

For that you can use something like the following code:

```
 require(plotrix)
 # rearrange data
 plotdata <- Data
 id <- plotdata < -30 | plotdata > 30
 plotdata[id] <- sign(plotdata[id])*35
 # plot histogram
 hist(plotdata,
      xlim=c(-40,40),
      breaks=c(-40,seq(-30,30,by=5),40),
      main="Untailed Data",
      xaxt='n'   # leave the X axis away
      )
 # Construct the X axis
 axis(1,
      at=c(-40,seq(-30,30,by=10),40),
      labels=c(min(Data),seq(-30,30,by=10),max(Data))
 )
 # add axis breaks
 axis.break(axis=1,breakpos=-35)
 axis.break(axis=1,breakpos=35)
```

This gives you :

[image]

Note that you get raw frequencies by adding `freq=TRUE` to the `hist()` function.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is essentially what @James suggests.  This is problematic for values in (-1,1), especially those close to the origin:

```
x <- seq(-2, 2, by=.01)
plot(x, sign(x)*log10(abs(x)), pch='.')
```

[image]

Something like this may help:

```
y <- c(-log10(-x[x<(-1)])-1, x[x >= -1 & x <= 1], log10(x[x>1])+1)

plot(x, y, pch='.')
```

[image]

This is continuous.  One can force C^1 by using the interval (-1/log(10), 1/log(10)), which is found by solving d/dx log10(x) = 1 :

```
z <- c( -log10(-x[x<(-1/log(10))]) - 1/log(10)+log10(1/log(10)),
         x[x >= -1/log(10) & x <= 1/log(10)],
         log10(x[x>1/log(10)]) + 1/log(10)-log10(1/log(10))
       )
plot(x, z, pch='.')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as another answer, because although the idea is similar, the mapping is fundamentally different.

When small values (<1) are included in a log-scaled plot, it is typical plot `log(1 + .)` rather than `log(.)`.

Reflect across the origin, and we get something useful:

```
x <- seq(-2, 2, by=.01)   
w <- c( -log10(1-x[x<0]), x[x==0], log10(1+x[x>0]))

plot(x, w, pch='.')
```

It should be clear that the function is smooth, as the directional derivatives around 0 will also be reflected.
[image]

With much larger values in x:

```
x <- seq(-10000, 10000, by=.01)
w <- c( -log10(1-x[x<0]), x[x==0], log10(1+x[x>0]))
plot(x, w, pch='.')
```

[image]